# When camera is initially off, picture in picture does not show the camera toggle - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, picture-in-picture

I'm building a video conference web app using ReactJS. Now, I have an issue, where if I initially has the state of `isUseVideo === false` means that the user's camera is disabled, and I open the PiP mode, the PiP will not show the camera toggle, so I'm unable to toggle it on through the PiP mode.

```
useEffect(() => {
    navigator.mediaSession.setMicrophoneActive(isUseMicrophone);
    navigator.mediaSession.setCameraActive(isUseVideo);
    try {
      navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler("togglemicrophone", () => {
        console.log('User clicked "Toggle Mic" icon.');
        if (isAllowUnmute) {
          navigator.mediaSession.setMicrophoneActive(!isUseMicrophone);
          dispatch(setUseMicrophone(!isUseMicrophone));
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(
        'Warning! The "togglemicrophone" media session action is not supported.'
      );
    }

    try {
      navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler("togglecamera", () => {
        console.log('User clicked "Toggle Camera" icon.');
        navigator.mediaSession.setCameraActive(!isUseVideo);
        dispatch(setUseVideo(!isUseVideo));
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(
        'Warning! The "togglecamera" media session action is not supported.'
      );
    }
  }, [isUseMicrophone, isUseVideo]);
```

This works fine for the microphone though. Am I missing something here?